# Retrieve the corresponding element from another data set?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, similarities, manifold-learning, transfer-learning

The problem is not necessarily related to NLP, just hopefully by putting it this way it will help illustrate the problem.

I have the pronunciations of a set of words from different people and myself for training.
At test time I'll have my own pronunciation of every word.
Given the pronunciation of a new word from a random person, I want to find out among my own pronunciations which is that word. 
What model should I use?

---

Currently what I'm doing is like, I trained a network that tries to learn a feature space where different pronunciations of the same word are close to each other. Then given the pronunciation of a new word, I'll just find the closest of mine to it in the feature space.

It works fine, just it feels that the set of my pronunciations might all lie in a subspace of the feature space (say the pronunciations from different people follow a Gaussian distribution, and my special pronunciation happens to lie on the left tail). So I guess there is something I can to improve it, like mapping all the embeddings to the subspace where my embeddings live in. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a standard feed-forward neural network will do what you want?

- input data: other person's pronunciation
- target value: your pronunciation

According to how much data you have, you can vary the depth of the network (1 or more layers), and how many neurons in each network etc.

If you dont have much data, keep the network shallow, few neurons, add a bunch of regularization (l1, l2, dropout ...)

I dont think its really transfer learning as such. Transfer learning would be:

- you have tons of data mapping from eg a written sentence to how someone pronounces it
- you train on this (using supervised learning probably)
- then you have a few examples of your pronunciation of one or more written sentences
- and you train on these sentences, but somehow bring across all the awesome knowledge that was learned on your earlier huge dataset

Comment: great point, thanks. just I suppose it's a bit hard to use audio data directly as the target value since they're of various length, I think I can try first convert the pronunciations into feature embeddings using the network I have, then do the regression using another network as you've suggested, how does that sound?